# Bing search API. Colon in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse a [Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_%28search_engine%29) search XML result, but whenever I try to access an XML element there is colon in every element.

It gives the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /

Here is my PHP code

```
foreach ($searchresponse->web:Web->web:Results as $result)
{
    printf(" \n%s", $result->web:Description);
}
```

Here is the Bing XML response,

```
<SearchResponse Version="2.2">
-
<Query>
    <SearchTerms>ipl</SearchTerms>
</Query>
-
<web:Web>
<web:Total>2430000</web:Total>
<web:Offset>0</web:Offset>
-
<web:Results>
-
<web:WebResult>
<web:Title>Indian Premier League | IPLT20</web:Title>
```

What is the meaning of colon in XML tags?

Answer (score 0):

Colons in XML nodes denote a namespace. It's likely you will be able to parse your XML more easily with something like [DOM](http://uk.php.net/dom) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which both have support for namespaced nodes. There's a good article [here](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/01/07/using-simplexml-to-parse-rss-feeds/) which discusses simpleXML and namespaces.

Comment: Shouldn't every XML parser support namespaces, as they are a part of XML?